# how to create sections dynamically in uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, sections

I am trying to build add sections dynamically to an existing uitableview. The data are in one table with parent style.

parent 1

- child 1
- child 2

parent 2

- child 3
  ...

Each parent should be a section and each child should be on that section.
I don't know how much sections I will have, and I don't know how much children for one parent I will have.

Is any way to do implement this ?

Thnx

Comment: the naive and quick solution would be an array which contains other arrays (the parents) which contain child objects.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the number of sections and reload tableView

```
 var numberOfSection:Int = 0
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return  numberOfSection
}
```

and if you load data from CoreData or network, load your data on background queue and reload tableview on main queue

```
  func updataData(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)){
       // load your data...
       // numberOfSections = ....
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two options:

One is to just call

```
func reloadData()
```

on the tableView and have it rebuild using the dataSource methods. It's the simplest way but can end up with weird animations

The other is to use

```
func insertSections(_ sections: [AnyObject],withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

to add the new sections in